# PayPal successful transactions not recorded in dashboard (sandbox)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I've just uploaded the PayPal APIs to test my scripts, and so far, they seem to be working properly (*all in sandbox mode*). Payments are processed, and the transaction details are returned, but for some reason, the transactions are not being recorded on the PayPal dashboard.

I tried the IPN simulator, using the sample script from GitHub, but keep getting this error:

**IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified.**

The script works; at the very least, it writes a log file when called from any browser. But not when called from PayPal's IPN simulator.

Could really use some pointers in the right direction. TIA.

Comment: Hi iSofia - since you're submitting all Sandbox transactions; and to be clear when you say 'paypal dashboard' you are talking about the sandbox.paypal.com dashboard correct?  Just getting clarity as the IPN response does not update or have anything to do with transactions in the paypal sandbox account. As far as your IPN is concerned, If we're trying to ping back a file and not unable to there it has to be permissible, file or server type related in most cases not all. Here is a good IPN reference that may help you: https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/

Comment: @GeekNinja: Thank you for your reply. There are two issue. First, when a successful sandboxed transaction (not IPN simulation) is performed, the dashboard should display the transaction under the sandbox transactions section, right? And second, since the transactions were not appearing in the dashboard, I decided to try the IPN simulator. Here, I keep getting *IPN not sent* and there is no activity whatsoever by my IPN script *(it writes a log file regardless of success or failure)*. If I called my IPN listener script from any web browser, the log file is written, meaning it's reached. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are [HERE](http://prntscr.com/c9ufla), then yes you "should" see them, however that dashboard is not very reliable. This is why I asked for clarity on 'what' dashboard you're looking at and posted the URL of sandbox.paypal.com.

---

2. If you're able to ping your IPN listener but PayPal is uanble to, try [defining and enabling the IPN URL](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) in the sandbox account and see what happens. From there you'll notice an IPN history link where you can see the status of the IPN call from that transction. If it failed, it will give you the error and you can troubleshoot from there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, which has answered my misunderstanding. Firstly, the transactions dashboard clearly indicates that successful transactions would not be displayed - totally escaped my attention. Secondly, the IPN is apparently not part of the standard transaction process, but an extended feature for added notifications *(right?)* As long as a payment is CREATED, EXECUTED, and returned APPROVED, the deal is done. *(right?)*

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped with your understanding. Yes, the IPN is a validation feature of the transaction. So, a completed payment is reported at PayPal, and the IPN URL you define, whether in the  notify_url= or in the paypal account is pinged and asked to validate the variables you have in the script.  So, (1). Added notification feature - Yes |  (2) yes, to this #